# How to change the numbering for different figures?

Tags: floats, numbering

Let's say I have two standard figures and two supplementary figures. If I change the name of figure using `\renewcommand{\figurename}` the figure counter will still count all figures continuously (i.e. *Fig 1, Fig 2, Supp Fig 3, Supp Fig 4* – see code below). How can I reset the figure counter so it will count standard figures separately from supplementary figures?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[footnotesize]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In preamble,

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure}]{suppfigure}
```

In text,

```
\begin{suppfigure}
\caption{...}
\end{suppfigure}
```

If you use old versions of `caption` package, there is no `newfloat` package, then use `caption` package and `\DeclareCaptionType` command instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\setcounter{figure}{0}` to reset the `figure` counter. However, as noted by lockstep in the comments, this will cause the number of the next "normal" figure to be wrong, as demonstrated in the example below, which has two `Figure 2`.

Another option is to define a new float style with the `float` package.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[footnotesize]{caption}

\newfloat{suppfig}{tbh}{losf}
\floatname{suppfig}{Supplementary Figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{suppfig}[htb!]
\caption{}
\end{suppfig}
\begin{suppfig}[hb!]
\caption{}
\end{suppfig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Resetting the `figure` counter will cause wrong numbering of the next "normal" figure (unless one saves and restores the former value). If the OP's aim is to *"count standard figures separately from supplementary figures"*, the correct way seems to be to define  different float types, as Leo Liu already did in his answer.

Comment: @lockstep Of course, and I agree. I'll add a note about this in my answer.