# How can I change figure caption label?

Tags: floats, captions

I am using `revtex4-1` for a Physical Review Letter. Typically when a figure is made, the caption starts out `FIG. 1. <text>`. I am creating a supplementary file and I would like it to say `FIG. S1. <text>`. How can I change that?

Comment: have you seen [how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A global modification to `\thefigure` of the form

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
```

would suffice (in your document preamble). Alternatively, if you only want to modify the figure number representation in the caption *only* (since you might not be referencing it as part of "supplementary figures"), you could use

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename~S\thefigure}
\makeatother
```

The former is preferred, since it makes more sense.

Comment: @egreg i would like to add some color in the figure's label, but i want the color  also applied in the colon that is added automatically after the figure number, and is appearing black,

    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{\color{magenta} \textbf{Figure}}

i am using memoir class

Comment: @SofiaMouseti Please ask a new question.