# Add the word "Supplementary" in the caption title of longtblr

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, longtblr

The `longtblr` caption title does not change from "Table" to "Supplementary Table", as the `table` caption title does. Indeed, **in the `longtblr` caption title, I would like to add the word "Supplementary" just before the word "Table". How can I do it?**

Here following you can find a MWE, with the corresponding result, and the document class I used (that contains the command to add the word "Supplementary", i.e. `\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{Supplementary \tablename~\thetable}`):

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,fleqn,10pt,dvipsnames,table]{wlscirep_modified}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, tabularx, longtable}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfp} 
\usepackage{color}

\title{Supplementary Information for...}
\author[1]{Luke}
\affil[1]{University of }

% Add longtable and xcolor packages and define a color
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF} 

\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}



\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section*{Supplementary Text}
\subsection*{Notes about ...}
This is about...



\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Condition & n & p \\
\hline
A & 5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
B & 10 & 0.01 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:example}Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\end{table}


\rowcolors{1}{white}{white}



\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
    }


\begin{longtblr}[  theme=fancy, caption = {This is a summary of...},]
        {
            colspec={m{0.9cm} m{0.1cm} m{0.6cm} m{1cm} m{3cm} m{7.3cm} m{1.5cm}},
            column{6}={preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
            row{1}={font=\bfseries}, 
            row{2,5,7-8,11-13,20-26,30,33-34,36,39-40,42}={bg=white},
            hline{1,Z}=0.8pt, hline{2}=0.4pt, 
            hline{4,8,10,12-13,15-19,21-26,28-29,32,34,38,40}=dotted, 
            hline{3,5-7,9,11,14,20,27,30-31,33,35,36-37,39,41,42-43}=solid,
            rowhead=1
        }

        Day
        &
        & Month
        & Hours
        & Event
        & Description
        & Further Info
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        Friday
        & $6$
        & February
        & 08 $-$ 19
        & Musical festival
        & 
        Something here ...
        & Multiple 
        \\
        %-------------------------------------------------
        \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 8 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{l} February
        & 08
        & Birthday
        & On Saturdays...
        & Multiple 
        \\
        &
        &
        & 9
        & Local Cup \newline
        & Soemthing here...
        & Single
        \\
        % -------------------------------------------------
    \end{longtblr}



\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Document Class**

This is my document class, i.e. `wlscirep_modified`, which is a modification of `\documentclass{wlscirep}` (that you can find in "[Template for submissions to Scientific Reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eALXC.png)"):

```
%
% An unofficial LaTeX class for Scientific Report articles.
%
% Copyright Overleaf (WriteLaTeX) 2016.
%
% Based on the SelfArx document class.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[18/03/2016, v1.1]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[03/11/2016, v1.2]
% \ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[27/02/2017, v1.3]
\ProvidesClass{wlscirep}[08/08/2020, v1.4]
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{courier}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}

\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}



% Settings for the author block
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\setlength{\affilsep}{1.5em}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}}

\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
                right=2cm,%
                top=2.25cm,%
                bottom=2.25cm,%
                headheight=12pt,%
                letterpaper]{geometry}%
                
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                justification=raggedright]{caption}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% Set up of the bibliography style

% \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[superscript,biblabel,nomove]{cite}
%% Nov 3, 2016: Support DOI
\bibliographystyle{naturemag-doi}
              
%
% headers and footers
%
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{}%
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{\small\sffamily\bfseries\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule

%
% section/subsection/paragraph set-up
%
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries\itshape}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}

%
% tableofcontents set-up
%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\small\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  
  
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}#1.}

%
% article meta data
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\def\@keywords{#1}}

% MODIFICATION 1 - comment all the abstract
% \def\xabstract{abstract}
% \long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract 
% \long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
% \def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
% \typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
% COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
% \gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
% NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
% THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
% \go}

%
% custom title page 
%
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@title\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@author\par}
\vskip18pt%
{%
\noindent
{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\color{color1}\large\sffamily\textbf{ABSTRACT}}}
}%
\vskip10pt
{%
\noindent
\colorbox{color2}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
% \sffamily\small\textbf\\\theabstract
}%
}%
% \vskip18pt%
% \noindent
% \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
% {\color{color1}\keywordname\hspace*{1em}} \@keywords%
%}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}%
}%
%-----------------------------------------------
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text 
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Color of section headings
\definecolor{color2}{gray}{1} % Color of the box behind the abstract
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords:} % Defines the keywords heading name

\newlength{\tocsep} 
\setlength\tocsep{1.5pc} % Sets the indentation of the sections in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Show only three levels in the table of contents section: sections, subsections and subsubsections

\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text
%-----------------------------------------------
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{-\tocsep}\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
}
%% Automatically abbreviate journal names
\RequirePackage{jabbrv}

% MODIFICATION 2 - Add the word "Supplementary"
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44115/how-can-i-change-figure-caption-label
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Supplementary \figurename~\thefigure}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{Supplementary \tablename~\thetable}
\makeatother
```

Compared to the original document class there are only two modifications, i.e.:

```
% MODIFICATION 1 - comment all the abstract
% \def\xabstract{abstract}
% \long\def\abstract#1\end#2{\def\two{#2}\ifx\two\xabstract 
% \long\gdef\theabstract{\ignorespaces#1}
% \def\go{\end{abstract}}\else
% \typeout{^^J^^J PLEASE DO NOT USE ANY \string\begin\space \string\end^^J
% COMMANDS WITHIN ABSTRACT^^J^^J}#1\end{#2}
% \gdef\theabstract{\vskip12pt BADLY FORMED ABSTRACT: PLEASE DO
% NOT USE {\tt\string\begin...\string\end} COMMANDS WITHIN
% THE ABSTRACT\vskip12pt}\let\go\relax\fi
% \go}
```

and

```
% MODIFICATION 2 - Add the word "Supplementary"
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44115/how-can-i-change-figure-caption-label
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Supplementary \figurename~\thefigure}
\renewcommand{\fnum@table}{Supplementary \tablename~\thetable}
\makeatother
```

**EDITED after the @Celdor's answer**

Thanks a lot @Celdor! Just a doubt.. Is it normal that the **Supplementary Table 2** caption title, related to  `\begin{longtblr}[theme = supplementary, ...` is **smaller** than the **Supplementary Table 1** caption title, related to

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Condition & n & p \\
\hline
A & 5 & 0.1 \\
\hline
B & 10 & 0.01 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:example}Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
\end{table}
```

as shown in the following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I would like to add the word "Supplementary" just before the word "Table". How can I do it?*

`tabularray`, specifically with `longtblr` as well as `talltblr` works along templates. Each component of a `longtblr` and `talltblr` has a template. By default `tabularray` creates two templates `default` and `empty`. The former is applied to all elements by default. Changing the `default` template changes all tables created via `longtblr`/`talltblr`.

In order to change a tag name from `Table` to `Supplementary Table` in a specific table, the first step would be to create your own template, say `supplementary`, for the caption components and caption itself. Since `longtablr` applies three separate caption templates when table is on the first, middle, and the last page, that is for `firsthead`, `middlehead`, and `lasthead`, you have to apply the same (or different) caption template for each one. It might look complicated at first but in the end it provides a lot of flexibility.

In your specific case, you would need to add the following to your code:

```latex
% Define and setup templates
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}{
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{supplementary}{Supplementary Table \thetable}%
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{supplementary}{.}%
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{supplementary}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{supplementary}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
\DefTblrTemplate{lasthead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
% Apply templates%
\NewTblrTheme{supplementary}{
  \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
  \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{supplementary}
  \SetTblrTemplate{middlehead}{supplementary}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lasthead}{supplementary}
}
```

See the code below for the MWE

In therms of regular tables and captions, I would recommend working with templates, as well. For instance, you could create a template `bfdot` for custom captions. `caption` provides commands for that, e.g.

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{bfdot}{\textbf{#1}.~#3}
```

Then such template could applied either locally inside `table` env. or globally in both cases using `\captiosetup{fromat=...}`. See code of the MWE.

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,fleq]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

% tabularray's internal package is recommended for improved formatting, including vertical bars 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% Define and setup templates
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}{
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{supplementary}{Supplementary Table \thetable}%
  \DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{supplementary}{.}%
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{supplementary}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{supplementary}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}\par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
\DefTblrTemplate{lasthead}{supplementary}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}}
% Apply templates%
\NewTblrTheme{supplementary}{
  \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
  \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead}{supplementary}
  \SetTblrTemplate{middlehead}{supplementary}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lasthead}{supplementary}
}
% Define and apply caption template in regular tables
\DeclareCaptionFormat{bfdot}{\textbf{#1}.~#3}
\captionsetup[table]{format=bfdot}

\title{Supplementary Information for...}
% \author[1]{Luke}
% \affil[1]{University of}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Supplementary Text}
\subsection*{Notes about ...}
This is about...

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Condition & n & p \\
    \hline
    A & 5 & 0.1 \\
    \hline
    B & 10 & 0.01 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Legend (350 words max). Example legend text.}
  \label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = supplementary,
  caption = {This is a summary of...},
  ]{
  width = \textwidth,
  colspec = {m{1.5cm} m{0.1cm} m{0.9cm} m{1.5cm,mode=math} m{3cm} X[m] m{1.5cm}},
  column{6} = {preto={\minipage{\linewidth}}, appto={\endminipage}},
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries}, 
  row{2,5,7-8,11-13,20-26,30,33-34,36,39-40,42} = {bg=white},
  hline{1,Z} = 0.8pt,
  hline{2} = 0.4pt, 
  hline{4,8,10,12-13,15-19,21-26,28-29,32,34,38,40} = dotted, 
  hline{3,5-7,9,11,14,20,27,30-31,33,35,36-37,39,41,42-43} = solid,
  rowhead = 1,
  }

  \SetRow{mode=text}Day
  &
  & Month
  & Hours
  & Event
  & Description
  & Further Info
  \\
  % -------------------------------------------------
  Friday
  & 6
  & Feb
  & 08 - 19
  & Musical festival
  & 
    Something here ...
  & Multiple 
  \\
  % -------------------------------------------------
  \SetCell[r=2]{l} Saturday 
  & \SetCell[r=2]{l} 8 
  & \SetCell[r=2]{l} Feb
  & 08
  & Birthday
  & On Saturdays...
  & Multiple 
  \\
  &
  &
  & 9
  & Local Cup
  & Soemthing here...
  & Single
  \\
  % -------------------------------------------------
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks@Celdor !!! Please see my ***EDITED*** part in my original question about a silly doubt I got after implementing your solution into my code :-)

Comment: Np. The content inside `\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{supplementary}{...}` is nearly a regular paragraph. As such, it accepts almost any formatting macro. For instance, in order to achieve right alignment, change `\centering` to `\raggedright`. `ragged2e` package defines a much improved version `\RaggedRight` which also adds hyphenations. You could also try to change `\centering` to `\raggedright\hangindent1.25cm\hangafter1` and have a hang-out caption by 1.25cm. For more sophisticated formatting, you would need to apply boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Celdor !! :-) .....but I think there has been a tiny misunderstanding... Is your comment related to the **size of the captions titles**? I was indeed talking about the size of ***Supplementary Table 2*** caption title (related to ```longtblr```), which is smaller than  the size of ***Supplementary Table 1*** caption title (related to the classical ```table```).. :-)

Comment: I assumed caption size rather than font size. my bad. On my end, they look the same while I can see your screenshot shows otherwise. It's likely due to a custom document class and custom style, which my approach does not pick. You can adjust it by yourself. For regular tables use `\captionsetup[...]{..., font=<size>}` where `<size>` keyword must be `normalsize` or `small` etc. (see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) for more key words). For `tabularray` use a regular paragraph macro : `\normalsize` or `\small` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) Very kind!