# How to create new subfloats?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

Using `\newfloat`, new float environments can be created and as exemplified in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures) post, I created a new float called `suppfig` but I want to add subfigures in it. When I simply add subfigures inside it I get the message:

> No counter `subsuppfig` defined.

When I add a counter called subsuppfig with `\newcounter{subsuppfig}` then I get

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

How do I define a new subfloat environment?

---

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newfloat{suppfig}{tbh}{supp}
\floatname{suppfig}{Supplementary Figure}
\begin{suppfig}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{ }
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{ }
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{...figurecaptions...}
\end{suppfig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's fine, but next time read the links posted. A minimal example should use images that are available to anyone. Either use the `draft` package option for [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) or use some of the images provided by the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

Comment: @Werner thanks.. I did not know about the mwe package.

Comment: @Werner  Isn't `caption` necessary for `subcaption`? I always believed so.

Comment: [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) loads [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). If you look at the [`subcaption` code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.dtx) you'll see a call to `\RequirePackage{caption}[..]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `newfloat`, a package designed to work well with `caption` and friends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure}]{suppfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{suppfigure}
    \begin{subsuppfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering\rule{.9\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{a small supplementary figure}
\end{subsuppfigure}\hfill%
    \begin{subsuppfigure}{.45\textwidth}
        \centering\rule{.9\linewidth}{2cm}
    \caption{another small supplementary figure}
\end{subsuppfigure}
\caption{And a captin for all of them}
\end{suppfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) works well (in an automated way) when using [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) for float creation. However, if you're using [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) or [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow), you're going to have to do the legwork yourself.

The following is taken from the [`subcaption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) (section **5 The `\DeclareCaptionSubType` command**):

> For using the sub-caption feature of the `caption` package some commands and counters must be prepared. This is done with
>
> ```
> \DeclareCaptionSubType[<numbering scheme>]{<type>}
> \DeclareCaptionSubType*[<numbering scheme>]{<type>}
> ```
>
> For the environments `figure` & `table`, and all the ones defined with `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` offered by the `newfloat` package, this will be done automatically, but for other environments (e.g. the ones defined with `\newfloat` offered by the `float` package or `\DeclareNewFloatType` offered by the `floatrow` package) this has to be done manually.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,graphicx,subcaption}


\newfloat{suppfig}{tbh}{supp}
\floatname{suppfig}{Supplementary Figure}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{suppfig}
\renewcommand{\thesubsuppfig}{\Alph{subsuppfig}}

\begin{document}

\begin{suppfig}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{First subcaption}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Second subcaption}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{suppfig}

\end{document}
```