# Custom numbering of figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, numbering

I'd like to number figures in a custom way.
For example: fig. 1, fig. 2a, fig. 2b, fig. 3 (among figures there is text).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Es.}
\end{figure}

Bla bla bla

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Es.}
\end{figure}

bla bla

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Es.}
\end{figure}

bla

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Es.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You might take a look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures, and specially this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

Comment: Hello @Cragfelt I was wrong to accept the link which you posted. How can I come back?

Comment: Is there *any* logic in this numbering scheme? And `\centering\begin {center}`???

Comment: Why not using the `subcaption` package?

Comment: Hello @ChristianHupfer I'd like to learn how do it in different ways.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to change the caption name ("Figure ") you can just use

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
```

To customize the counter, you have to redefine `\thefigure`. If you want to manually choose the counter every time, just write something like

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{2a}
```

before each figure. The default implementation of `\thefigure` uses an automatically incrementing counter:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

where `figure` is a counter, see for example [this](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Customizing_numbering_pages.html). Note that you have to revert the `\thefigure` command to the default value if you want to stop customizing your labels and get an automatically incrementing counter again. You can use `\setcounter{\thefigure}{2}` to set the value of the counter.

[image: figs]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\begin{document}

    Bla bla bla
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{1}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}

            \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Es.}
    \end{figure}

    Bla bla bla

    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{2a}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}

            \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Es.}
    \end{figure}

    bla bla

    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{2b}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}

            \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Es.}
    \end{figure}

    bla

    \setcounter{figure}{2}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}

            \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);   

            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Es.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```